# Portfolio Grid random spacing @media query

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid, portfolio

I'm using "Megafolio" jQuery plugin (http://codecanyon.net/item/megafolio-gallery-jquery-plugin/980161) on this site: http://www.playwinterpark.com/activity_directory_summer.html . Everything works perfectly until the smallest mobile resize, which creates some really interesting whitespace randomly after (or before) some of the images (i.e. between "biking" & "boating" Between "golfing" & "hiking". Has anyone dealt with this issue before? And Most importantly, how can I resolve this?! Anything helps. My code is below.

Thanks in advance!

**IMAGES CSS:**

```
.cell1x1, .cell1x2, .cell2x1, .cell2x2 {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

**PORTFOLIO SCRIPT OPTIONS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                <!--    PORTFOLIO   -->
                 $("#products").portfolio({ 
                    <!-- GRID SETTINGS -->
                    gridOffset:6,               <!-- Manual Right Padding Offset for 100% Width -->
                    cellWidth:150,                      <!-- The Width of one CELL in PX-->
                    cellHeight:150,                     <!-- The Height of one CELL in PX-->
                    cellPadding:6,                      <!-- Spaces Between the CELLS -->
                    entryProPage:30,                        <!-- The Max. Amount of the Entries per Page, Rest made by Pagination -->

                    <!-- CAPTION SETTING -->
                    captionOpacity:75,

                    <!-- FILTERING -->
                    filterList:"#portfolio-filter",     <!-- Which Filter is used for the Filtering / Pagination -->
                    title:"#selected-filter-title",     <!-- Which Div should be used for showing the Selected Title of the Filter -->                                              
                    <!-- Page x from All Pages -->
                    pageOfFormat:"Page #n of #m",       <!-- The #n will be replaced with the actual Item Nr., #m will be replaced with the amount of all items in the filtered Gallery-->                      
                    <!-- Social Settings-->
                    showGoogle:"no",                    <!-- Show The Social Buttons ...-->
                    showFB:"no",
                    showTwitter:"no",
                    urlDivider:"?",                     <!-- What is the Divider in the Url to add the Variables, Filter and Image ID . Impotant for WordPress i.e. Social will share this link with this divider -->

                    showEmail:"no",                         <!-- ADD EMAIL TO LINK ALSO TO THE LIGHTBOX  -->
                    emailLinkText:"Email to Friend",
                    emailBody:"mailto:email@echoecho.com?body=I found some great File here #url",   <!-- The #url will be replaced with the url of the image -->
                    emailUrlCustomPrefix:"http://www.themepunch.com/",                              <!-- Use this if you wish a Custom Prefix to Link Path -->                      
                    emailUrlCustomSuffix:"?ref=...",                                                <!-- Use This if you wish to use a Custtom Suffix for Link Path -->


                    <!-- BACKGROUND -->
                    backgroundHolder:"#main-background",
                    backgroundSlideshow:0
                })  





        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since you have the images hard coded in your html you might want to put a mediaQuery for mobile that makes all your images' width to 100% ....something like this:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
   /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
   .catall img {
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```